# OkHttp Post not getting data sent on the server side

Tags: java, android, post, okhttp

I am trying to send token to the server using OKHTTP library but am not getting the post request sent from the application.

I have already added the internet permission in my Manifest.

```
private void registerToken(String token) {

        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("token", token)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://####/push_notifcation/index.php")
                .post(formBody)
                .build();

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            Log.i(TAG, "ok");
            Log.i(TAG, response.message());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
            Log.i(TAG, "nok");
        }
    }
```

Server

```
if(isset($_POST["token"])){
    $token = $_POST["token"];

    $db_data = $database->insert("tokens", [
        "token" => $token
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct so some more information will be needed. From what is provided my best guess would be http is being redirected to https and maybe losing the POST body or something along those lines.

A way to help debug this is to add a `NetworkInterceptor` that logs the HTTP requests so you can dive into what is actually happening. Here is a runnable example configuring [OkHttpClient logging](https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/okhttpclient-logging-configuration-with-interceptors)

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpUtil.class);
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging =
    new HttpLoggingInterceptor((msg) -> {
        logger.debug(msg);
    });
logging.setLevel(Level.BODY);

client.addNetworkInterceptor(logging);
```

If you can add the debugging output to your question we can dive deeper if there is no issue with http -> https redirects.

Just a note `OkHttpClient` are thread safe and are meant to be used by many threads. It's good practice to have one `OkHttpClient` that is reused (per specific configuration). You can make a static instance or dependency inject it in. Creating one per method call will have overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void send(JSONObject obj){
    new OkHttpClient().newCall(new Request.Builder()
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .url("URL...")
            .post(RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"),
                    obj.toString())
            ).build())
    .enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Log.d("ZAKA",e.getMessage());
        }
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            Log.d("ZAKA","Report : -> "+response.body().string());
        }
    });
}
```

Then Call it

```
JSObject obj = new JSObject();
obj.put("token","your token");
send(obj); // Call send method
```